# Changing background-images with a fade inbetween

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the background images of my hero section with JS. The loop is working but I'm not sure how to have one image fade into the next.

The way that it is currently set up makes it fade to white (the background colour) inbetween changes, rather than fading from one image to the next.

```
var images = ["../images/winter.jpeg", "../images/spring.jpeg", "../images/summer.jpeg", "../images/welcome.jpeg"];
var index = 0;

function changeBackground() {

  index = (index + 1 < images.length) ? index + 1 : 0;

  $('.hero').fadeOut(0, function () {

    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')')

    $(this).fadeIn(0);

  });
};

var timer = null;

function startSetInterval() {
  timer = setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
}
// start function on page load
startSetInterval();

$('.link-block-animation').hover(
  function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
  },
  function () {
    timer = setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
  });
```

Comment: Maybe, a work around, could be using :before and :after, with position absolute, adding an animation of fading. before with z-index 1 and after with z-index 2, add a fade out animation to after, and when finished, change the background image on after and make its opacity 1 again, or in case jquery  doesnt let you get the pseudo classes, using divs

Comment: make a reproducible example, pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is use absolute positioning on the `.hero` elements. Every time you want to change the background, you can then insert a new `.hero` with `display:none` on top of the old `.hero`. For absolute positioning to work you can add a container with `position:relative`. That way, you can be sure that all the `.hero` elements are at the exact same position. So your html and css could look like this:

```
<style>
.container{
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
.hero{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero"></div>
</div>
```

Now, using javascript, you can add a `.hero` to the container, which will show on top. Since we want it to fade, we first set `display` to none, then fade it in. After fading in we can remove the old `.hero`. Something like this:

```
var index = 0;

$('.hero').css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');

function changeBackground() {
    var oldHero = $('.hero');
    var newHero = $('<div class="hero"></div>');
    index = (index + 1 < images.length) ? index + 1 : 0;
    newHero.css('display','none');
    newHero.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
    $('.container').append(newHero);
    newHero.fadeIn(1000,function(){
        oldHero.remove();
    });
};
```

Does that come close to what you need?